# Iterating over Conv2D layers of a pre-trained model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using progressive learning for making a model for classification. I first used vgg16 weights and add a Dense layer at the end to train the model.

```
prior = keras.applications.VGG16(
    include_top=False, 
    weights='imagenet',
    input_shape=(48, 48, 3)
)
model = Sequential()
model.add(prior)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', name='Dense_Intermediate'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1, name='Dropout_Regularization'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid', name='Output'))

for cnn_block_layer in model.layers[0].layers:
    cnn_block_layer.trainable = False
model.layers[0].trainable = False
```

I froze the vgg layers so their weights do not change. After training, I saved the weights.

```
model.save('model65x65.h5')
```

I increased the dimension of the images using ImageDataGenerator and loaded previously saved model weights and I defined a new model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(96, 96, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(96, 96, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

prior = load_model('./model65x65.h5')
```

Now I wanted to add all but the first two layers of VGG16 to the new model, strip the input layer out and also strip out the first convolutional layer using

```
for layer in prior.layers[0].layers[2:]:
    model.add(layer)

# re-add the feedforward layers on top
for layer in prior.layers[1:]:
    model.add(layer)

# the pretrained CNN layers are already marked non-trainable
# mark off the top layers as well
for layer in prior.layers[-4:]:
    layer.trainable = False
```

As there are convolutional layers in the VGG16, I keep getting this error when I try to iterate over the prior model.

**AttributeError: 'Conv2D' object has no attribute 'layers'**
How can I iterate over the Conv2D layers?

Comment: I haven't got any error with this code. Can give a bit more context?

Comment: @Yoskutik I got the error 'AttributeError: 'Conv2D' object has no attribute 'layers'' while iterating over the Conv2D layers of the pre-trained model. I want to remove some layers because they were trained for the input of 48x48

Comment: `prior.layers[0]` refers to a single layer of the VGG model. So `prior.layers[0].layers` should give an error. Try `prior.layers[2:]` instead, like you did in your other loops.

Comment: Doing that gives me this error 'ValueError: Error when checking target: expected max_pooling2d_8 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (128, 2)'